# React-Native and Expo: Any different between create-react-native-app and react-native init

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I need some clarify of the difference between create-react-native-app then detached and react-native init.

I understand that the former one will create an app based on the expo and later require detached to expose the native code of android and iOS for native code implementation. The react-native init will generate the native code at the same time.

Are there any difference after detach from expo after created from create-react-native-app command, compared with react-native init?

Answer (score 0):

The only significant difference is that you still depend on the Expo SDK. From the website:

> We call this "detaching" because you still depend on the Expo SDK, but your project no longer lives inside the standard Expo client. You control the native projects, including configuring and building them yourself.